# Custom font not working ubuntu font

Tags: css

I have downloaded the Ubuntu font to use on my webpage

```
#link-r {
    color: white;
font-family: "ubuntu";
font-size: 16px;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntu'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu.tff'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in which browser it is not working? Please make sure that font type is available in the mentioned path.

The @font-face rule is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

However, Internet Explorer 9 only supports .eot type fonts, while Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support .ttf and .otf type fonts.

Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the @font-face rule.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code to your website:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

For more info, please take a look [Here](http://www.google.com/fonts/#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3a)